# Primary key not returned in OneToOne join fetch in eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I have an issue join fetching in case of OneToOne relation in the same class. Example follows:

```java
class Data {
 ...

 @Id
 @Column(name = "DATA_ID")
 Long id;

 @Column(name = "DATA_OWNER_ID")
 @ForeignKey(entityClass = Owner.class)
 Long ownerId;

 @Column(name = "DATA_RELATED_ID")
 @ForeignKey(entityClass = Data.class)
 Long relatedDataId;

 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "DATA_RELATED_ID", referencedColumnName = "DATA_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
Data relatedData;

}
```

I want to select data based on some conditions, while also fetching/initialising the "relatedData", all in one JPQL query:

```
SELECT owner.something1, data
FROM Data data
JOIN Owner owner on data.ownerId = owner.id
JOIN FETCH data.relatedData
WHERE data.something2 = :expectedSomething2
```

Executing that JPQL query throws an exception:

```
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="relatedData" referenceClass=Data)|Exception:
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [DatabaseRecord(
DATA_X => something
DATA_Y => something2
...
)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.  Primary keys must not contain null.
```

Which is somewhat true, as there is no DATA_ID column listed. Changing `JOIN FETCH` to `LEFT JOIN FETCH` returns both `owner.something1` and `data`, but the `relatedData` object is null (relatedDataId is not null).

I can see, that the id for relatedData is returned from DB, but eclipselink trims it in valueFromRowInternalWithJoin and trimRowForJoin methods.

Comment: What was the SQL issued for the query - does it look correct? What version of EclipseLink are you using?

Comment: @Chris - Query is correct. The ``Data`` table has 91 columns. Generated query returns 183 - 91 for ``data``, another 91 for ``data.relatedData`` and one for ``owner.something``. As I said, everything is fine until eclipselink messes it up in ``trimRowForJoin`` method call on initial 193 - trimming it down "too much". Eclipselink version is 2.6.2.

Comment: Query SQL may be correct, but the format of the results is involved in the problem - which is why I ask. Simplify a test case to just an entity with a few columns and you are more likely to find a solution - or the applicable bug as I recall vaguely there being one with self references which seem to be involved here.  Does the query work if you remove the select for owner.something1 and the join to owner? I suspect the problem is purely related to the data object and its self references, but hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

The ***Id column name attribute value*** is the reason of this exception. Same issue found in **eclipselink version  2.3.2**  but it works fine in **version 2.0.0**
*Try with this entry :*

```
eclipselink.jpa.uppercase-column-names=true
```

**OR** Try with **upper and lower case one by one** which on will work for you.

```
@Id
@Column(name = "UUID")   // UUID - uppercase/lowercase one by one
Long id;
```

Comment: That depends on the database being used - this only matters if the DB/JDBC driver returns column names in a case that is different than what was defined. Most will return case-insensitive names as upper case. Such a problem would have existed across all EclipseLink versions.

Answer (score 0):

I've somehow resolved this issue, but haven't had the time to correctly identify the cause. Final (working) version differences are:

1. I could've forgotten to add get/set for `relatedData`
2. I have specified `targetEntity = Data.class` in `@OneToOne`
3. Fetch is now a `LEFT JOIN FETCH` and appears before `JOIN Owner owner`